# keep complete type of a function pointers parameters in template deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

I'm trying to get a way to keep the complete type of a function pointer's parameters when passed into a template function.

This is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

template<typename _Ret, typename... Args>
static _Ret call(_Ret (*fp)(Args&&...), Args &&... args)
{
    return fp(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int foo(int arr[4])
{
    printf("arr: %i,%i,%i,%i\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    return 0;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int (*foo_ptr)(int arr[4]) = &foo;
    call<int>(foo_ptr, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the type that call actually sees foo_ptr as `int (*)(int*)` rather than `int (*)(int [4])` or `int (*)(int (&)[4])`.

The reason for the rvalue references is that is the only way to keep the array's type at all, but it doesn't seem to work for function pointer parameters.

As to why I want to do this, I have a nearly magical lua binding lib that is 100% template based, and requires no code to link to. In order for it to be able to support binding to properties and variables that are arrays themselves the rvalue references are required. `int*` and `int (&)[4]` are not compatible types.

The idea is to allow binding existing apis, even C apis as transparently and automagically as possible, while doing as much of the type checking at compile time as is possible.

Is this possible at all?

---

Edit:

Ok, my example was probably a bit too simplified. I can't actually change the definition of the functions that get passed into "call", as this library is meant to allow binding to any random function a user might want.

here for example is my static function (non method) binding method:

```
template<typename _Ret, typename... _Args>
LuaGlue &func(const std::string &name, _Ret (*fn)(_Args...))
{
    auto new_func = new LuaGlueFunction<_Ret, _Args...>(this, name, fn);
    functions.addSymbol(name.c_str(), new_func);
    return *this;
}
```

And LuaGlueFunction happens to look like this:

```
template<typename _Ret, typename... _Args>
class LuaGlueFunction : public LuaGlueFunctionBase
{
    public:
        typedef _Ret ReturnType;
        typedef _Ret (*MethodType)( _Args... );

        LuaGlueFunction(LuaGlueBase *lg, const std::string &n, MethodType fn) :
            g(lg), name_(n), fn_(std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn))
        { }

        ~LuaGlueFunction() {}

        std::string name() { return name_; }

        bool glue(LuaGlueBase *luaGlue)
        {
            lua_pushlightuserdata(luaGlue->state(), this);
            lua_pushcclosure(luaGlue->state(), &lua_call_func, 1);
            //printf("add function: %s\n", name_.c_str());
            lua_setglobal(luaGlue->state(), name_.c_str());
            return true;
        }

        int invoke(lua_State *state)
        {
            ReturnType ret = applyTuple(g, state, fn_, args);
            lua_pop(state, Arg_Count_);
            stack<_Ret>::put(g, state, ret);
            return 1;
        }

    private:
        LuaGlueBase *g;
        std::string name_;
        MethodType fn_;
        std::tuple<_Args...> args;
        static const unsigned int Arg_Count_ = sizeof...(_Args);

        static int lua_call_func(lua_State *state)
        {
            auto mimp = (LuaGlueFunction<_Ret, _Args...> *)lua_touserdata(state, lua_upvalueindex(1));
            return mimp->invoke(state);
        }
};
```

I'm attempting to allow the detection of an array, and then autobox it in a LuaGlueStaticArray type internally (that part already works, assuming I can keep the array from decaying into a pointer).

Hopefully that helps explain a little better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `int (*)(int*)` and `int (*)(int [4])` are two spellings of the same type. `int (*)(int (&)[4])` is a differtent type, but the template won't produce it out of thin air, you need to pass an entity of that type in.

Comment: indeed, you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem with the `call` function template. It needs to be defined as

```
template<typename _Ret, typename... Args>
static _Ret call(_Ret (*fp)(Args...), Args &&... args)
//                             ^^^ no &&
```

You want perfect forwarding for the arguments you pass in, but you do no want to force the types of the function parameters to reference types.

Next, when you pass an array to a function it *decays* to a pointer to the address of the first element. So your function `foo` is actually equivalent to

```
int foo(int *arr)  // size information is lost
```

Keeping this in mind, you do not want `arr` to be deduced as `int (&)[4]` when you pass it to `call`, so you must pass a pointer.

```
call<int>(foo_ptr, &arr[0]); // pass a pointer to the beginning
```

After making these changes your code works. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ebf34c93fff6728)

---

If you want to preserve the array's size when passing it to `foo`, change that function to

```
int foo(int (&arr)[4])
{ ... }
```

And then call it as

```
decltype(foo)* foo_ptr = &foo;
call<int>(foo_ptr, arr);
```

---

As [mpark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2968284/mpark) points out in the comments, in both examples above there's no need to explicitly mention the return type of `call`, or form the function pointer `foo_ptr`. The calls can simply be

```
call(foo, &arr[0]);    // with int foo(int *arr)
```

or

```
call(foo, arr);        // with int foo(int (&arr)[4])
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a603e511688b1eb0)

Comment: Note that if the type of `foo` is `int (int (&)[4])` then you can simply call it as `call(foo, arr);` [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/674ec8f88756283c)

Comment: @mpark Yep, that is what I did in the [second link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a603e511688b1eb0) I posted. Or did you mean there's no need for `foo_ptr`? If so, I agree, I only did it because the OP did it in the question.

Comment: no need for `foo_ptr` yes, but also,the explicit template parameter: `call<int>`

Comment: @mpark Ah yes, that is worth mentioning. I've updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Deducing the types of the actual parameters to `call` separately from the formal parameters to `fp` allows for implicit conversions to take place, so that both `call(foo, &arr[0])` and `call(foo, arr)` are valid ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d77d2996b0aac716)).

Comment: I can't actually change the function's parameters. This is for a binding library, that is expected to allow to bind to any api. The way I'm actually trying to do this is significantly more complex than this example, it ends up passing the function pointer type through a couple templates and tuples... Also the reason for foo_ptr was just to see if that would "convince" the compiler to remember the array parameter's type.

Comment: @Tomasu You're going to have to make the first change (changing `Args&&` to `Args` in the function pointer parameter type) unless you want `call` to [only accept functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8806289b8c3274f) with rvalue reference parameter types.

Comment: I did try that, but it doesn't actually work. gcc gives: `inconsistent parameter pack deduction with ‘int*’ and ‘int (&)[4]’` which means it is decaying the type of the function pointer's parameter. I want to be able to detect array types so I can "Wrap" them automatically. See my edit above.

Comment: @Tomasu Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c978ce911c0a248) solve your problem? Now a reference to the array is being passed to `foo`, and it is not decaying to a pointer. Or maybe you can switch to `std::array` and pass reference to that around. Otherwise can you please reduce the `LuaGlueFunction` example to something I can compile? (get rid of the base class and other extraneous stuff)

Comment: @Praetorian the idea is to not have to change the apis you are binding to when using this library. But how often do people actually specify functions that take explicit arrays like this? I don't see too many. supporting std::array is probably a good idea regardless. I just wish it was possible to handle this transparently. grr. some c apis I see will do `int blah[]` or `int *blah[]`. and id like to handle that. but I gather it isn't possible without modifying it to read `int (&blah)[]` etc?